# Root /home Directory vs ~ (tilde)

Tags: root, directory-structure, home

I have created a virtual image for Scientific Linux and came across this after I finished installing it:

```
[root@ftpserver home]# pwd
/home
[root]@ftpserver home]# ls
```

When I `cd` into `~` I get this:

```
[root@ftpserver ~]# pwd
/root
```

What is the overall difference between `/home` and `/root`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEROOTFILESYSTEM):

```
/home : User home directories (optional)
/root : Home directory for the root user (optional)
```

A typical non-root user's home directory would be `/home/$USER`. `/root` is also special in that (in many distros) `/root` is readable only to root (`700`), but a normal user's home directory has read access to others (`755`) as well.

Answer (score 5):

In case of trouble during booting (resulting in other volumes not being mounted) it helps that `root` (which is used for repair logins) has its home directory available. `/home` is often on a different volume.

Answer (score 3):

`/home` is where all users usually get their home directories created under.

Examples:

```
/home/marcelo
/home/joe
```

The `/home` may sometimes reside in a different filesystem (i.e., a separate harddisk, another partition in the same harddisk or even network mounted) than the `/` (main system's filesystem).

For this (and probably other reasons as well), the root user's home directory is normally in a separate directory that resides in the main system's filesystem, thus not risking the chances of not being mounted due to network connectivity or other issues.

All this is configurable and, theoretically, you could have your system root's home under `/home` as well, for example `/home/root`, but this is not recommended.

The `~` symbol is just something the shell replaces with the current user's home directory.  It is not, per se, a valid path.